# whats the difference between these two css selectors?

Tags: css

Whats the difference between these two selectors, I thought they would have the same effect, but they don't? can someone explain please?

```
    #parent-div #child-div

    #parent-div#child-div
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The (space) in CSS selectors is the "descendant selector."

1. Selects an element with ID `child-div` that has an ancestor of `parent-div`
2. Selects an element that has an id of both `parent-div` and `child-div` (which is impossible)

*Just for fun*: `parent-div#child-div` is a valid ID, but as part of the CSS syntax you have to escape the `#` in the ruleset:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/xdWNV/1/

Answer (score 2):

I believe the second one is wrong because it means your element has 2 ids called (1) parent-div and (2) child-div

Answer (score 1):

the first one selects item with id child-div that is the descendant of item with id parent-div, the second one won't work because it selects item with both id parent-div and child-div