# What is the difference between these two CSS expressions?

Tags: css

I have two css expressions:

```
.firstexpression.secondexpression (without space)
```

and

```
.firstexpression .secondexpression (with space)
```

What is the difference?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036156/whats-the-difference-between-css-classes-foo-bar-without-space-and-foo-bar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126338/difference-between-classa-classb-and-classa-classb-in-css, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763313/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-css-selectors?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

The first applies to elements with BOTH classes applied, the second to a child element with `.secondexpression` with a parent with `.firstexpression`

```
.firstexpression.secondexpression{
   /* styles */
}
```

Applies to:

```
<div class='firstexpression secondexpression'>Applies to this element</div>
```

Vs..

```
.firstexpression .secondexpression{
   /* styles */
}
```

Applies to:

```
<div class='firstexpression'>
   <div class='secondexpression'>Applies to this element only</div>
</div>
```